# Python function outputs duplicate values

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, beautifulsoup, function

I have defined a function that scrapes data from a webpage. On this webpage there are 25 search results (property-listings in my case). I've written code to find all 25 of these listings and then tried to use a for loop to call my function on each listing on the webpage. However, the output shows the same listing printed 25 times. I would like to know if it's possible to apply my function `details()` to all 25 property-listings on the page found with:`listings = soup.find_all('article',{'role' : 'article'})`. Then I need those results outputted into a CSV file.

I'm using Python 2.7

Here is what I have so far:

```
output = []
property = []

def address():
    for address in soup.find('span', {'itemprop' : 'address'}):
        property.append(address.text)
def sqft():
    for sqft in soup.find('dl',{'class' : 'property-info-sheet pier-5'}):
        property.append(sqft.text)
def lot():
    for lot in soup.find('dl',{'class' : 'property-info-sheet pier-6'}):
        property.append(lot.text)
def built():
    for built in soup.find('dl',{'class' : 'property-info-sheet pier-7'}):
        property.append(built.text)

def details():
    address()
    sqft()
    lot()
    built()

    file = 'output.csv'
    with open(file,'wb') as f:
       writer = csv.writer(f)   
       writer.writerow(property)

listings = soup.find_all('article',{'role' : 'article'})

for listing in listings:
    details()
```

This outputs the same listing 25 times. Is it possible to get each listing once instead of one listing 25 times?

Answer (score 1):

Your soup.find_all and soup.find calls are unrelated so there is no point in looping through listings right now. You will need to send in listing to details as such:

```
for listing in listings:
    details(listing)
```

and in details refer to listing instead of soup

```
def address(soup):
   ...
def sqft(soup):
   ...
def lot(soup):
   ...
def built(soup):
   ...
def details(soup):
   address(soup)
   sqft(soup)
   lot(soup)
   built(soup)
```

Comment: I'm not following this. If I send listing into details `details(listing)` the loop ends in an error: 'Nonetype' object is not iterable.

Comment: Now you get to the dirty parts of parsing with BeautifulSoup. Returned values are of various types, including possibly None. Find here is meant to return a single value, but you are iterating through it. This is possible with some types but not others. I would recommend getting rid of the for loop or switching to a find_all.